# Drag and drop to generate fields like WordPress widget area using JqueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-ui

I was trying to program a drag and drop form builder like WordPress widget area. Well, following is my sample left nav bar(it is the source)

```
<ul id="form-fields">
   <li id="text-field">Text Field</li>
   <li id="textarea-field">Text Area</li>
   <li id="select-field"mySelect</li>
   <li id="radio-field">Radio Button</li>
   <li id="checkbox-field">Checkboxes</li>
   <li id="password-field">Password</li>
   <li id="file-field">File Upload</li>
</ul>
```

And my empty form (destination) is as followes

```
.Containt{ width: 100%; height: 800px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; background-color:#ffff00;}
<div  class="Containt"></div>
```

I have generated a JqueryUI script as following:

```
$(function() {
 $('#text-field').draggable({
        revert: "valid",
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
    });
 $(".Containt").droppable({  
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( '<div class="col-md-8"></div>' ).html('Check the 1st new figure: <input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" value=""/ >').appendTo( this );
        }
    }).sortable({
        cursor: "move",
        items: "div:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
      }
   });    
});
```

These code combination does generates a html text field as I declared in `html` but problem is I can only drag-drop & generate only a single element like a text field from the TextField option. But can't do others. I have tried `$('#form-fields li').draggable({` but I can't generate an automatic field (like Text Area for text-area, Text Field for text-field command). It only works for one source, one destination. But I want this to work same like Wordpress widget area.
http://jsfiddle.net/abmmhasan/9WzeD/

Answer (score 1):

```
    <style type="text/css">
 .Containt{ width: 100%; height: 800px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; background-color:#ffff00;}
#form-fields li .val{display: none;}
.Containt li .val{display: inline-block}
.Containt li .txt{display: none}
.ui-draggable-dragging .val{display: none !important}
    </style>

    <script>
   $(document).ready(function()
{

$('#form-fields li').draggable({
        revert: "valid",
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
    });
$(".Containt").droppable({  
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function(event, ui) {   

    /* Remove Comment if want to use each element once.
         var self = $(this);
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();
    */
         var newclass = "road";
         // change class name whatever you want

        // 
        var item = ui.draggable.html(); 
        var s =item; 
        var r = /<span>(.*)<\/span>/g;
        var newtxt=s.replace(r,""); 

        $("<div></div>", {            
            "html": newtxt,
            "class": newclass
        }).appendTo(this);   
    }


    }).sortable({
        cursor: "move",
        items: "div:not(.placeholder)",
      sort: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
      }
    });

});
    </script>
    <body>
    <ul id="form-fields">
        <li id="text-field"><span>Text Field</span><input type="text" name="textbox" class="val" /></li>
        <li id="textarea-field"><span>Text Area</span><textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="val"></textarea></li>
        <li id="select-field"><span>mySelect</span><select class="val"><option value="option1">option1</option></select></li>
        <li id="password-field"><span>Password</span><input type="password" name="pwd" class="val" /></li>
    </ul>

<div  class="Containt"></div>
    </body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LftNd/6/

Comment: Well, I commented that 2 line to make it multiple drop but a new problem is sortable function seems not working (as tested your code on jsfiddle)!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abmmhasan/9WzeD/
Only text field works.
This is what my initial work is. I only want my result in content area. & also your script doesn't support draggable sort like mine. Check it. See my posted question again.

Comment: just another little work need: your script is bringing in the source too, but I only wanna bring in result. Well, I wanna say that it will only bring in what ever in span area nothing else. Your script is bringing in menu name+span value but I only want span value. (As the output rendered in  http://jsfiddle.net/abmmhasan/9WzeD/)

Comment: this will work for you http://jsfiddle.net/LftNd/4/ . this will give only value and hide text

Comment: Problem again! It is bringing in '.' means <li>. I have tried to replace "<li></li>"(in droppable section) with '<div class="road"></div>' but alas that not worked! I don't understand why it stops working when I change "<li></li>". What should I do?
Another thing is you are using "dispaly:none", this thing actually just hides the code but it is actually inside the code on generated form which is not a good practice & spoils the generated form!

Comment: i updated code in http://jsfiddle.net/LftNd/5/ and answers section above. this will help you.

Comment: Nice thing that you optimized the code, but still class in div not working do I have to work with some addClass function? I mean in my destination form I want <div class="road"></div>, means I wanna bring in a class with div too! How can I do that?
Another thing, if I wanna execute an external command like I declared another JS function me(a,b), when dropped that function will be executed. & also with parameter transferring like me(a,b).
Actually, I already appreciated really what you did for me. You seems to be good with the knowledge & I think you can help me with this too.

Comment: Adding css class in destination form please check this http://jsfiddle.net/LftNd/6/ or answers section above too. you want too add another JS function can you give me live link (jsfiddle) what exactly you want to add?

Comment: 1. I wanna execute a function on drop, like
drop: function(event, ui) { 
...........
func_name(a,b)
}
The func_name function is declared outside this. the parameter a,b will transfer value of generated field (like "<input type=text ....>") and the position. Even if I sort the generated inputs the position value will be transferred again.
2. Also there will be a Delete option for every generated field after drop.

Comment: Added code for delete option for generated filed after drop. Reefer this http://jsfiddle.net/LftNd/7/

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want to add while drooping. Provide me JSFiddle link regarding new JS thing, after than only i can help you further.

Comment: For suppose, I placed 3 box in destination(containt)! For every box dropped or sorted will generate code. Like, in our project in generated form we have 3 element 1. text field, 2. Email field, 3. submit button. Now if I click on generate button it will produce the code of that form which can be view-able or downloadable! This thing I can't show you in jsfiddle coz I don't have such. & see in wordpress after I drag drop they save that code for that widget area in Database. I wanna know how to do it (no need the above function call as I said in previous comment)!